# How to add collision in gltf file with A-frame?

Tags: collision-detection, aframe, gltf, ammo.js

My cube does not collide with gltf model. I already tried everything (including [Ammo.js collision detection of GLTF model in A-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311696/ammo-js-collision-detection-of-gltf-model-in-a-frame)), but my code does not work.

The full code in https://a-frame-collision-with-gltf.glitch.me

```
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-extras@6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://mixedreality.mozilla.org/ammo.js/builds/ammo.wasm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-physics-system@4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.js"></script>
    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('explode', {
            init: function() {
                var el = this.el;
                el.addEventListener("collidestart", function () {
                    console.log('collision detected');
                    el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
                });
            }
        });

        AFRAME.registerComponent("autofit-gltf-ammo-sphere", {
          init() {
            this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", () => {
                this.el.setAttribute("ammo-shape", "type:sphere");
                this.el.setAttribute("ammo-body", "type:kinematic; emitCollisionEvents: true");
            });
          }
        });     
    </script>

    <a-scene physics="driver: ammo; debug: true; gravity: -9.8; debugDrawMode: 1">

        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="lowpolylandscape" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/56205a53-63c6-43af-b8e7-7e755e8503c5/lowpolylandscape.gltf"></a-asset-item>
            <!-- There is a scene.bin in the same directory -->
        </a-assets>

        <a-camera position="0 1.6 20"></a-camera>

        <a-box
            color="red"
            scale="1 1 1"
            position="0 5 -6"
            ammo-body="type: dynamic"
            ammo-shape="type: box"
        ></a-box>

        <a-entity
            gltf-model="#lowpolylandscape"
            position="0 0.7 0"
            rotation="0 270 0"
            explode
            autofit-gltf-ammo-sphere
        ></a-entity>
        
    </a-scene>
```

Comment: did you try it without jade, to check if the issue is with `a-frame` or with jade (like the order of rendering html elements)?

Comment: Thank you @PiotrAdamMilewski for your answer. But I tried without jade and the error continue. I edited my post and the full code is on https://a-frame-collision-with-gltf.glitch.me

Comment: Check the console - `ammo-shape` looks for a body, which is not yet present. You need to set `ammo-body` first. There are some issues with fitting the mesh ([glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hulking-boundless-eucalyptus?path=index.html%3A26%3A55)), but I guess if you want the physics engine to fit the body to the model, you might need to split it to land / trees / etc.